# Make First line height in textview the same as other lines

Tags: android, textview, android-view

I have a recyclerview with bunch of textview each as an item as you see in picture below. (Blue lines aren't really there, i added them so you can see each item separately) as you can see everything seems nice and user will not notice the text is separated.

The problem is when user increases the line space(a typical option in app) line height gets bigger except the first and last line of each item and the result seems like second picture.

My question is how to find appropriate padding to set to each item so every line height seen exactly the same?

BTW i can not use just one textview for many reason!

[image]

[image]

Comment: hii @Alireza please post the xml code for the textView if possible

Comment: You should use CardView for better Visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the divider height of your listview according to linespacing height.

Or you can set an invisible view at the bottom of every row item and increase the height of this view according to linespacing height.

Or you can set padding at the bottom of every row item and increase the value of this padding according to linespacing height.

Comment: "increase the value of this padding according to linespacing height." I know that!! my problem is how can i find right padding size based on line height?

Comment: @Alireza Use like android:lineSpacingExtra="10px" and you will know your spacing value. And in java, use setLineSpacing(x, y);

Comment: Perfect solution! I was using lineSpaceMultiplier to increase or decrease line space so i was so hard to figure out exact line space value after each change. By using lineSpaceExtra instead everything made so easy!

Comment: @Alireza Thanks.  If you accept my answer as Correct answer. I will be happy :)

Answer (score 1):

just add some padding to the parent of your textview in the layout file of your list item .

for example the layout with linearlayout would be like :

```
<LinearLayout ........
paddingTop=15dp>

<TextView  
..........>
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and you could adjust the padding dynamically if you want.

Comment: If i do that when app launches first time it seems ok but use can change line space in the app, I need to adjust this padding whenever user changes the line height. My question is how can i find the padding after each change to line height? what's the formula?

Comment: you could just add a newline to the end of every string and that would be ok ... jus add "\n" to the end of strings @Alireza